# Leaflet.js image overlay now showing

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

So I have been making a map for a game called starscape. For adding all the different systems to this leaflet map I use an image overlay to then add the systems respectively, but now after some time of development the image doesn't show even in the DOM on the overlaylayer, and no errors show up. The source is on github and I usually don't compile/serve it with webpack or firebase when testing but I do when deploying it (https://github.com/robigan/Starscape-Utils and the website I deployed to https://starscape-maps.web.app/). I have been scratching my head at this for a couple hours and Idk what to do anymore. I use the python3 module LittleHTTPServer when testing. Note that this has been happening for some while now and I had forgot to init git some I have no history to revert to.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ffs, found out, but I am gonna leave this post open because I find this *interesting*, in the end I added the image overlay function towards the end. So after my population function was running and my custom controller was called. It finally showed up